# TypeScript Function to dynamically set an entire Column range's value to eg. AD1, AD2, AD3, etc

Tags: excel, typescript, office-scripts

World

I am trying to write a function that will dynamically setValues on the whole range of column AE to "AD" + i (with my assumption that i would be the incrementing value) This is the function I'm using but all it does is write AD5 into the first 5 columns, not AD1, AD2, AD3 etc...

```
for (let i =1; i <=5; i++) { 
    // Set AE2 to AE5. 
    let rowID = range.setValue("AD" + i);
}
```

I'm sure it is something simple and stupid... Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Here is the complete  code:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, sheetName: string, address: string, base64ImageString: string) {
    let sheet = workbook.getWorksheet(sheetName);
    let range = sheet.getRange("AE2:AE5");
    
    for (let i =2; i <=5; i++) {
        // Set AE2 to AE5.
        let rowID = range.setValue("AD" + i);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more context because `range` hasn't been declared there.  There's clearly more code above that `for` statement.  It might help us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you're loop is actually writing out against all cells in the `range` variable so every time it goes around, it will write AD1, AD2, AD3, etc. in **ALL** cells.

Given you're looping 5 times, the last entry written will be AD5 and you don't even see the previous values.  You can watch it and you'll see what I mean but don't blink or you'll miss it.

I've modified your script to make it do what you want but with an approach I'd be taking.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, sheetName: string, address: string, base64ImageString: string) {
  let sheet = workbook.getWorksheet(sheetName);
  let range = sheet.getRange("AE2:AE5");
  let rowCount = range.getRowCount();

  for (var row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {
    let cellAddress = range.getCell(row, 0).getAddress();
    sheet.getRange(cellAddress).setValue(cellAddress.split('!')[1]);
  }
}
```

Have a look, digest it and see if it helps.

I hope I've understood correctly.

Comment: Genius, @Skin! You nailed it, and now I can see how to manipulate the cells... can't thank you enough for your help!

Comment: @EPStudio, no worries, always here ... always happy to help.

Comment: Hey @Skin, just trying to put this into production and realize, I need the result to populate in the column AE (not AD where it has to derive it's column name) Trying to use a getRangeOffset to in the sheet.GetRange line but that's not available at the worksheet level... Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, it's there, you kinda do it like this ... `sheet.getRange(cellAddress).getOffsetRange(0, 1).setValue(cellAddress.split('!')[1]);` ... that'll write the data one column forward from that which is defined in the range, which in this case, is AD (as you describe and if I've understood correctly).  I'm a little confused by what you're doing but you can see how the offset works there.

Comment: Bingo! @Skin, I am buying you a virtual beer right now! That is the $ right there!! Woohoo!! Thanks :)

Comment: @EPStudio ... and I'll take that virtual beer!

Comment: Wish there was a way to give you a badge or something... Don't quite understand Stack rewards yet lol

Comment: Mate ... your success is the only reward I need lol

Comment: Hey, @Skin!  I have posted another question thinking you might have some thoughts? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71253205/typescript-office-script-to-force-image-compression-in-excel-workbook

Answer (score 0):

you may Misunderstood the meaning of this method **range.setValue**

1. when you call the method, it will fill all the range, so all cells are the value of your last traversal
2. if you want to implement your purpose you could Traverse all cells and set the cell, **not the range**

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in the past by putting the following in cell A1 and dragging down:

```
="AD"&row()
```

Drag as far as needed and copy paste.special values as needed. Never considered using vba though.