# TypeScript (Office Script) to force image compression in excel workbook

Tags: excel, typescript, office-scripts

Coding gurus

Is it possible to invoke something similar to this VBA code in excel online via Office Script?

```js
Sub test()

    Dim wsh As Worksheet
    Dim shp As Shape

    Set wsh = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    For Each shp In wsh.Shapes
        shp.Select
        SendKeys "%e", True
        SendKeys "~", True
        Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PicturesCompress"
    Next shp

End Sub
```

Basically, I am dynamically updating an excel online excel sheet with base 64 images into a shape container but I want the downloaded version of the sheet to automatically reduce the quality of the image, I know the 'compress picture' feature is not available in excel online so am looking for a workaround so that when the downloaded excel sheet opens it automatically reduces image quality for all photos.

I have tried changing the preferences for the excel online version of the sheet (in offline mode) to lower quality images but the parameter seems to revert as soon as it goes back online...

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Comment: What type of images are they?  PNG?  JPG?  Could your images be of either type?  Also, would it not make sense to adjust the image before it goes into the workbook?  If you want a downloaded version of the workbook to have reduced quality images then why not do that for the version on SharePoint/OneDrive as well?

Comment: I’m pulling the base 64 data directly from a sharepoint list text column, and converting it to a shape in the excel online file using TypeScript to dynamically add the images to their corresponding item rows. They are mime/jpeg encoded binary that get render in the excel shape containers, so there is no opportunity or desire to convert them to jpeg or png image files beforehand…

Comment: Ok, but is there any reason why you can't change the quality of the image (don't worry about HOW it's changed) before it's added to the workbook?  If the base64 string is of type image/jpeg then we should be able to change the quality before it goes to Excel.  I see that as your point of opportunity.

Comment: I guess that’s what I’m going for, wanting to change the quality as it’s being pulled into excel and before being put into the shape container within the same Office script… it might not be possible

Comment: It's possible, leave it with me.

Comment: Aye aye!  Good luck! 

Comment: I hope that works for you.  Feel free to upvote the answer if it works for you, it was effort +.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, pay attention.  Also know that I have tested this and it worked for me.

Also, I have no idea of your knowledge on the below so I'm gunna treat you like a muppet and give you step by step instructions.

Go into the Azure Portal and create a new .NET Azure Function and call it `ChangeImageQuality`.  Now, in the code view, make sure you open up the bottom drawer so you can see the logs.

[image: Poral]

Before you copy in any code, you need to create a new file in the solution called **function.proj** and it needs to be saved with this content ...

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="SixLabors.ImageSharp" Version="2.0.0" /> 
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#referencing-custom-assemblies

When you save it, the logs should show (as in the screenshot above) that it's restoring the Nuget packages, etc. from the project file.

Now, back in your **run.csx** file, add the following code ...

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System;
using System.Net;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    var result = new MemoryStream(); 

    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);

    int quality = data.Quality;
    string base64Image = data.Image;

    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64Image));

    using (var image = SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.Load(memoryStream))
    {
        image.SaveAsJpeg(result, new SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.Jpeg.JpegEncoder()
        {
            Quality = quality
        });
    }

    return new ContentResult()
    {
        ContentType = "text/html",
        Content = Convert.ToBase64String(result.ToArray())
    };
}
```

That code assumes a few things, one being that everything is perfect with what you provide into it, i.e. there's a lack of error checking but it's pretty straight forward.

Now from LogicApps, you can call the function using the `Azure Function` connector and it will run and return to you a base64 string that is the image with the downgraded quality that you specified.

[image: Payload]

##### JSON Payload

```
{
  "Image": "@{variables('Base 64 Image')}",
  "Quality": 10
}
```

Naturally, you just need to change the variable to your base 64 instance along with the quality you want and then pass the response body into your `Run script` step.

[image: Run Script]

Like I said, I tested that and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Wow. Just wow... You are a freaking genius @Skin !!! Literally, this is some next level stuff, and thank you for the muppet approach as I am just wet behind the ears on this side of things, so man I can't thank you enough! I will attempt to implement this and let you know how things go. Incredible.

Comment: So… @Skin, turns out I don’t have access to azure portal so I can’t write an azure function  is there anyway we can do this just in Power automate using a component / Java script etc?

Comment: Not that I’m aware of. I thought you must’ve been using LogicApps, not PowerAutomate. If you have PowerAutomate then you’ll have an Azure instance by default. Do you have a mate in a team somewhere within your org that can help you out?

Comment: Also, if you’re using PowerAutomate then you’d need to use the HTTP/request action to do this anyway which requires a premium Licence. Are you paid up for that?

Comment: Ya I have premium connectors for power apps and power automate but even my azure admin doesn’t have access to function apps

Comment: When I sign in to our  azure admin page  and click on function apps it takes me to the sign up screen for Azure portal…

Comment: And I have admin rights in our azure space as well…

Comment: Yeah, that’s probably right. If you’ve never used Azure before, you’ll need to provide some info regarding credit card, etc. so it knows where to charge any costs. Don’t worry, there’s no charge for zero usage so if you have it and don’t use it, it’s no big deal.

Comment: ok... hang on, apparently the functions are always "free" if you sign up for the free account?

Comment: alright! I'm in!! :)

Comment: They're nominal from a charge perspective, you'll be lucky to see more than $2 a month unless they're long running and being triggered A LOT.

Comment: Ok. I'm stuck trying to add the funcction.proj file ... can't find anything called "Code + Test" or even the Developer tab... What am I missing?

Comment: can't seem to find the 'Code View' either! FML * facepalm*

Comment: See if this helps … https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-app-portal … try that first and then we’ll tackle the function.proj file.

Comment: I think i got the function.proj file built but I can't find the run.csx file? I know it's in the folder structure of the C# script?

Comment: So much to learn :-)

Comment: ok. I figured out to get to the code + text you have to create a function, the tutorial says to create an http function but your image doesn't show what type I have to create? help!!

Comment: Yeah, sorry, HttpTrigger as well. My answer wasn’t “muppet” enough.  :-)

Comment: bahaha... lol yes, you are dealing with the purebred muppet here...

Comment: You’re close now man. If you’re using PowerAutomate though, my answer will need to change slightly but I’ll talk you through it. I get the feeling you’re an Aussie?

Comment: and you called the http trigger ChangeImageQuality just like the function itself?

Comment: Hahah... Good ol' Canadian eh?

Comment: Well … the HttpTrigger is the function that should be called ChangeImageQuality, the function app (which can have more than one function) could’ve been called anything. You must’ve called the function app ChangeImageQuality as well … no harm done.

Comment: it says storage is not configured properly... Is that an issue I need to fix?

Comment: This might be easier over Teams/Zoom, what’s your preference?

Comment: Haha totally.. prob teams, zoom is a PITA LOL

Comment: Got an email address I can get you on?

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter at all... whatever is best for you!

Comment: Not sure if you got that invite?

Comment: there are no words to adequately explain my gratitude and your level of awesomeness! Thank you again, you are a grade A human! Cheers Mate!

Comment: All good man! Happy to help. You might want to delete your comment with your email address in it though. :-)

Comment: Wise you are good sir! Wise you are… 